# ASP Classic Cannot Save Changes in XML File

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I am working on a website that allows users to modify and save changes to values in a XML file. It works perfectly on my local server, but when I move the file to another server (the server on my company's system computer), the same code does not work and gives me a 500 Internal Server Error message.

I use JavaScript to take the user's input value and send the value to an ASP Classic file, which saves the value in the corresponding node in the XML file. The ASP code is:

```
Call Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
Dim objXMLDoc, root, node, info
info = request.querystring("i")
info = Split(info, "~")
Set objXMLDoc = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objXMLDoc.async = False 
objXMLDoc.load Server.MapPath("Standard.xml")
Set root = objXMLDoc.documentElement
Set node = root.selectSingleNode(".//interval[@id='"&info(2)&"'][@name='"&info(1)&"']")
node.Text = info(0)
objXMLDoc.save Server.MapPath("Standard.xml")
```

The problem is "caused by" the objXMLDoc.save statement (last line). The same code runs without any problem on my local server, so I wonder if it is because I do not have access to write to a XML file on the system server (but not sure and do not know how to grant the access). Does anyone can help me figure it out? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, it's almost certainly a permissions issue. Unfortunately, I don't know how to turn on the necessary permissions.

Comment: You need to enable Show Classic ASP Errors in Browser ( http://serverfault.com/questions/670853/iis-8-show-classic-asp-errors-in-browser ) and get the underlying error